# Fastest way to check if a hashtable has a specific value from a string split

Tags: c#, vb.net

Any help would be great thank you.

I have a string for example

```
Dim words As String = "Hello world i fell like badword"
Dim inputCheck As String = words.Split(New Char() {" "c})
```

With a hash table with words and replacement words

how would you loop through the hastable and replace the words that match?

```
For Each Item In hsTable

                Next
```

out come would be "Hello world i fell like *****" badword being replace with replacement word match in hashtable.

thank you.

Comment: You want to use C#'s foreach() control statement.

Comment: Please show some code on how you created `hsTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward.

```
dim result as new list(of string) 
for each word in inputCheck
  result.Add if(hsTable.Keys.Contains(word), hsTable(word), word)
next
dim replaced = string.Join(" ", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you are using a Hashtable?  This is very easy to do with a List of KeyValuePair.  Would something like this work?

```
Dim words As String = "Hello world i fell like badword"

Dim newWords As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
newWords.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("badword", "goodword"))
newWords.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("badword2", "goodword2"))

newWords.ForEach(Function(w) words.Replace(w.Key, w.Value))
```